# Show menu shortcuts in German

Tags: javafx, menu, internationalization, shortcut

I'm German. When I create a menu shortcut like this:

```
neu.setAccelerator(new KeyCodeCombination(KeyCode.N, KeyCombination.CONTROL_DOWN));
```

the shortcut is in English.

What do I have to do, so that the menu shortcuts are displayed in German?

Comment: What programming language are you using? Which platform is this code designed to run on?

Comment: What programming language are you using? Java. Which platform is this code designed to run on? Windows 10.

Comment: What programming language are you using? sorry JavaFX

Comment: while being not properly written the question is actually interesting. I cannot find a good solution, looks like in [AWT](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html) it was possible tho

Answer (score 1):

Not displaying modifiers in their localized version is [a bug that was recently reported](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8205655) (and doesn't look like anywhere near the top of the priority list for fixing). So we have to hack around it.

The basic idea is to replace the accelerator text after the normal processing has set it to the hard-coded English version. The example below does so in a custom Menu class in an onShown handler. Here it's simply hard-coded again, production code obviously would need to implement some kind of lookup of the correct localized version.

```
public class BugHackMenu extends Menu {

    public BugHackMenu(String text) {
        super(text);
        setOnShown(e -> hackAcceleratorText());
    }

    private void hackAcceleratorText() {
        getItems().stream().forEach(item -> {
            if (!needsHack(item)) return;
            Node menuRow = item.getStyleableNode();
            if (menuRow != null) {
                Node accText = menuRow.lookup(".accelerator-text");
                if (accText instanceof Label) {
                    Label acc = (Label) accText;
                    acc.setText(getHackedText(item.getAccelerator()));
                }
            }

        });
    }

    private String getHackedText(KeyCombination accelerator) {
        return accelerator.getDisplayText().replace("Ctrl", "Strg");
    }

    private boolean needsHack(MenuItem item) {
        KeyCombination acc = item.getAccelerator();
        return acc != null && acc.getControl() == ModifierValue.DOWN;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you.The Compiler say it doesn't like static at the class definition. What can I do?

Comment: Can you please make an Example how to translate Ctrl in Strg. I don't understand, sorry!

Comment: forgot to remove the static modifier, thanks for the heads up! There is no translation, just a replacement of the string that had been set by super's internals

Comment: Thanks. Can you make an Codeexample please? which methods have I call how?

Comment: Simply use that custom menu instead of the core menu, don't understand what's the problem. Maybe you want to read a decent tutorial on basic java and/or basic javafx? No offense meant, but ... if you can't apply that class in your context you have to learn some essentials first

Answer (score -1):

Is there a way that I can do this to the delete key! so instead of having "Delete" as a shortcut I can have "Del"
PS: I am using JMenuItem and KeyStroke!

`private JMenuItem delRef = null; del = new JMenuItem("delete"); del.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_DELETE, 0));`

And it's in java and on Unix

Comment: this looks more like a follow-up question than an answer, what is it? Anyway, JMenuItem is Swing (not javafx) .. so maybe your are also in the wrong tag :)